# I wish to Update one table from another table

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have my main table which lists all the USERS and I have an external database that will be updated periodically.

TABLE1: ID, USERNAME
EXTTABLE: ID, USERNAME

I need to only Update the USERNAME for each User ID.

```
Table1                     External Table
ID     USERNAME           ID     USERNAME  
A1     Joe                A1     Joe 
A2     John               A2     John 
A3     Bob                A3     Rodger 
A4     Fred               A4     Frank
A5     Bill               A5     Bill
```

I just want to Table1 with the new changes for each user ID. 
I figured a way to copy all the data from the external table by deleting everything and inserting the new table but I only want to update fields that have been changed because the user accounts will be linked to things.

I haven't done SQL in many many years so I cant remember any of the SQL side.
Thanks

Comment: you can do update over inner join

Comment: i've looked something up on INNER JOIN and it looks promising but I won't be able to try it until tomorrow.
If it works I will post the solution.

Comment: I used the relationship editor to create two Queries one will update existing records and the other will add new records if they are not present in the first table.

Comment: that's called merge

Comment: It seems to work by adding what I need, is there any downside to this method over the other?
I haven't fully tested it yet as ive just got home from work and got it done in the last 10 mins.

Answer (score 0):

Query to update existing records:
Field UserName
Table Table1
Update To [Table2]![UserName]

Field: [Table2]![UserName]
Criteral: <> [Table1]![UserName]

Relationship Between ID in both tables is joined to only include rows where the join fields from both tables are equal.

Second Query
Field: ID
Table: Table2
Append To: ID

Field UserName
Table: Table2
Append To: UserName

Field: Username
Table: Table1
Critera: Is Null

Relationship between ID:
Include ALL records from Table2 and only those records from Table1 where the joined fields are equal.